# Assign value to a variable using $_GET method in PHP

Tags: php

On index page, i have a link that looks like this

```
<a href="edit.php?id='.$prom.'"> Edit </a>
```

So, when i use `echo $_GET['prom'];` on edit.php page it outputs a value assigned to $prom, but when i do this

```
$id = $_GET['prom'];
```

an error occurs `Undefined index: prom in C:\wamp64\www\vezba\edit.php on line 4`

Can someone help me to assign a value that $prom holds to a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because `prom` is not defined on the url as a key to a value. When specifying the url like this `?id='.$prom.'"` the php will convert it to the associative array `$_GET` using the `id` as key and the value you defined in the `$prom` variable as value. This means that the `$_GET` looks like this:

```
$_GET = ['id' => $prom];
```

That's why the undefined exception is thrown and why you should access it like this:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

If you prefer to use this notation `$id = $_GET['prom'];` you must change the key specified on link for the prom value:

```
<a href="edit.php?prom='.$prom.'"> Edit </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$prom` is value. please use the key `id`

`<a href="edit.php?id='.$prom.'"> Edit </a>`

`$id = $_GET['id'];`